# Does SwiftUI have a Picker with typing to filter a big list?

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit

I wondering if I need to build this myself or if SwiftUI (or AppKit, I can use `NSViewRepresentable`) has something like it already. This is for a macOS app.

The user needs to choose from a very large list. In the example below I used animal names. There are dozens or maybe 100's of items. They can type some characters to narrow the list. Then they can click any item to choose it, or hit return to select the highlighted item, which could be the first item in the list, or maybe a recently used item.

[image]

Comment: This would probably be best done with Combine. You can have a `TextField` for the search query, and combine to filter the results.

Answer (score 0):

Single filtering list written in SwiftUI:

```
let animals = ["Cat", "Camel", "Dog", "Crocodile"]

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var searchString = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search", text: $searchString)
            List(animals.filter({searchString == "" ? true : $0.contains(searchString)}), id: \.self) { animal in
                Text(animal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can increase the model complexity according to your needs, and apply List selection (see documentation of SwiftUI). To support selection:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var searchString = ""
    @State private var listSelection: String? = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search", text: $searchString)
            
            List(animals.filter({searchString == "" ? true : $0.contains(searchString)}), id: \.self, selection: $listSelection) { animal in
                
                Text(animal)
                
            }
        }.padding()
        .onChange(of: searchString, perform: { value in
            listSelection = animals.filter({searchString == "" ? true : $0.contains(searchString)}).first
        })
    }
}
```